# How to Install the PHP SSH2 Extension on Ubuntu 14.04 running PHP 5.6?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, php5

I run `sudo apt-get install libssh2-1-dev libssh2-php` I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libssh2-php is already the newest version.
libssh2-1-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 71 not upgraded.
```

But it does not work. I don't see them installed when run `php -m |grep ssh2 #you should see ssh2`

What steps would you take next? One thing to note that when I ran `sudo apt-get update` I noticed that it's connecting to `http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse` . Could that be an issue?

Comment: Check your php.ini file

Answer (score 1):

To install ssh2 extension for PHP5 , run:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config php5-dev
sudo pecl install ssh2-0.13
```

Or

```
sudo pecl install https://pecl.php.net/get/ssh2-0.13.tgz
```

Restart the `php-fpm` service then verify it:

```
php -i | grep ssh2
```

[pecl : ssh2](https://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2)

Comment: I followed the instruction and the modules are available when I run php through apache. But not when I run php from command line. Any suggestions?

Comment: Usually there are 2 configuration files for PHP (php.ini) one for Apache and one for console (CLI). This means that Apache's configuration loads the extension while the console one don't.  Check /etc/php folder for them.

Answer (score 1):

[PHP-5.X + PHP-7.X Installation Instructions](https://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2) cover the difference.

It appear you must use a pecl install procedure when using PHP-5.X versions.